how to insert linebreak="goodebreak" or badbreak attrib in <mo> for passible line breaks in mathML through mathJax for LaTeX equation
I am creating and downloading MathML content through mathjax for LaTeX equation
The below script i used in HTML, for converting TeX to MathML, this script download the  "MathML_download.html", then i will extract the MathMl content from <math>...<math> for each equations.
I need to insert the linebreak="goodbreak"  in the  element for possible break position and need to insert linebreak="badbreak" for the not possible break position
How to get the linebreak attribute automatically insert in the MathML, through MathJaX or any other script available to insert attribute in the extracted MathML content
Using below Script for converting MathML from LaTeX (MWE):
<html xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async 
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>
<title>MathML to SVG Converter</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.resizeTo(50,50)" id="mytst">
<p>\begin{equation}\label{E:mm6}
\begin{aligned}
h(x) &= \int \left(
\frac{ f(x) + g(x) }
{ 1 + f^{2}(x) } +
\frac{ 1 + f(x)g(x) }
{ \sqrt{1 - \sin x} }
\right) \, dx\\
&= \int \frac{ 1 + f(x) }
{ 1 + g(x) } \, dx - 2 \arctan (x - 2)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href','data:text/plain;charset=utf-8, ' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML));
        element.setAttribute('download', "MathML_download.html");
        
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        element.click();
    }, 20000); 
}
window.onload = codeAddress;
</script>
</body>
</html>


A couple of things to consider:
First, might it not be easier to use a command-line tool like the ones in the MathJax node demos repository (like the tex2mml-page example in the components directory) to convert your tex to MathML?  You don't need to use the browser to do that.
Second, note that MathML-Core, which is all you can count on in native browser support for MathML, doesn't include line-breaking or the linebreak attribute.  So unless you are targeting something other than browsers, or are going to use a library like MathJax to do the display again later, you may not have any luck with specifying linebreak values even if you get them into your MathML.  MathJax v3 doesn't have line breaking either, but v4 (now out in beta release) does.
That being said, you can define macros in MathJax to allow you to add the linebreak attributes.  A simple version would be
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    macros: {
      goodbreak: '\\mmlToken{mo}[linebreak="goodbreak"]{}',
      badbreak: ['\\mmlToken{mo}[linebreak="badbreak"]{#1}',1],
      nobreak: ['\\mmlToken{mo}[linebreak="nobreak"]{#1}',1]
    }
  }
}

These are described in more detail in a discussion on the MathJax User's Forum.  The key things to note are that \badbreak and \nobreak each take an argument (the operator to use in the <mo> element holding the linebreak attribute), and that the argument is not processed further, so you can' use macros within it.
MathJax v4, since it has line-breaking support, has somewhat more sophisticated support for \goodbreak, \badbreak, etc., but you can back-port these to v3 with the following more extensive configuration.
MathJax = {
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['linebreaks']}},
  startup: {
    ready() {
      const {Configuration} = MathJax._.input.tex.Configuration;
      const {CommandMap} = MathJax._.input.tex.SymbolMap;
      const {BaseItem} = MathJax._.input.tex.StackItem;
      const NodeUtil = MathJax._.input.tex.NodeUtil.default;
      const {MmlMo} = MathJax._.core.MmlTree.MmlNodes.mo;
      
      NodeUtil.getOp = function (mo, form = 'infix') {
        return MmlMo.OPTABLE[form][mo.getText()] || null;
      };
      
      new CommandMap('linebreaks', {
        allowbreak: 'AllowBreak',
        goodbreak: ['Linebreak', 'goodbreak'],
        badbreak:  ['Linebreak', 'badbreak'],
        nobreak:   ['Linebreak', 'nobreak'],
        break:      'Break'
      }, {
        AllowBreak(parser, name) {
          parser.Push(parser.create('token', 'mspace'));
        },
        Break(parser, name) {
          parser.Push(
            parser.create('token', 'mspace', {
              linebreak: 'newline',
            })
          );
        },
        Linebreak(parser, name, linebreak) {
          let insert = true;
          const prev = parser.stack.Prev(true);
          if (prev && prev.isKind('mo')) {
            const style = 
              NodeUtil.getOp(prev)?.[3]?.linebreakstyle ||
              NodeUtil.getAttribute(prev, 'linebreakstyle');
            if (style !== 'before') {
              prev.attributes.set('linebreak', linebreak);
              insert = false;
            }
          }
          parser.Push(parser.itemFactory.create('break', linebreak, insert));
        },
      });
      
      class BreakItem extends BaseItem {
        get kind() {
          return 'break';
        }
        constructor(factory, linebreak, insert) {
          super(factory);
          this.setProperty('linebreak', linebreak);
          this.setProperty('insert', insert);
        }
        checkItem(item) {
          const linebreak = this.getProperty('linebreak');
          if (item.isKind('mml')) {
            const mml = item.First;
            if (mml.isKind('mo')) {
              const style =
                NodeUtil.getOp(mml)?.[3]?.linebreakstyle ||
                NodeUtil.getAttribute(mml, 'linebreakstyle');
              if (style !== 'after') {
                NodeUtil.setAttribute(mml, 'linebreak', linebreak);
                return [[item], true];
              }
              if (!this.getProperty('insert')) {
                return [[item], true];
              }
            }
          }
          const mml = this.create('token', 'mspace', {linebreak});
          return [[this.factory.create('mml', mml), item], true];
        }
      }

      Configuration.create('linebreaks', {
        handler: {macro: ['linebreaks']},
        items: {[BreakItem.prototype.kind]: BreakItem}
      });
      
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
    }
  }
}

See the 4.0.0-alpha.1 release notes for more details.  These macros work more like the actual TeX equivalents, as they don't take an argument.  Rather, they try to attach a linebreak attribute to the following (or sometimes preceding) <mo> element, or insert a new <mo> or <mspace> if there isn't one.
